# Jenkins doesn't refactor folder names, SonarQue gives response

Tags: java, git, jenkins, sonarqube

So I am using a continous integration path (IDE -> Github -> Jenkins -> SonarQube) and I had to refactor some package names (the first character was uppercase, not as it should be) to lowercase. However, sonarqube now gets stuck on the foldernames that Jenkins uses.

See, I had a package that was called 'DataStorageLayer' and I refactored to 'dataStorageLayer'. Sonarqube is giving me this error:

```
This file "DatabaseConnection.java" should be located in "dataStorageLayer" directory, not in "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/23ivp4d-bar/workspace/src/main/java/DataStorageLayer".
```

Could someone help me resolve this? Is there a way to tell Jenkins to update its folder names?

Comment: It recognizes the file is in a different directory. Can you check on the SonarQube server whether the rename ended up in a new directory being created? May be a clean is in order? Not sure if this is a bug/known issue in Sonar.

Comment: I can't see any new directory's being created. I do not however know what you mean by a clean? I'm new to the whole CI thing. @prabugp

Comment: Clean is when you clean up the binary output directories (like .class or generated jar files ) so that we get rid of any stale files. Typically happens when we rename/update a file and the tool we are using might not pick up or reflect the changes made.

Comment: I'm guessing you are referring to the directories that Jenkins has stored on the server? @prabugp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem on case-sensitive filesystems.

Rename the folder to something else, commit that, then rename it to what you want.

e.g

`DataStorageLayer` -> `dataStorageLayer0tmp` -> `dataStorageLayer`

You should be able to do this now, even after the existing failed renaming.

By the way, if these are java packages, by convention they should be all lowercase, without any uppercase letters at all.

Comment: This did the trick! And indeed they have to be all lowercase ;) Thanks for your help!